# Extra quotes being added to @Query

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "communication": {
      "office": {
        "email": "test@example.com"
      },
      "private": {
        "email": "test2@example.com"
      },
  }
}
```

I want to query dynamically for the email based on the type e.g. office or private. When I use the following command:

```
@Query(value = "{ 'communication.?0.email' : ?1 }")
Object findByEmail(String type, String email);
```

The

```
'communication.?0.email'
```

is converted to

```
'communication."office".email'
```

and mongo didn't find an entry. How can I avoid the quotes before and after office?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Im also being stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it was not required anymore and I stopped investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is spring mongo doesn't supports what you are looking for. Why you are not passing everything as parameter rather as below.

@Query(value = "{ 'communication.?0.email' : ?1 }")
Object findByEmail(String type, String email);

where email value should

```
type= "communication." + type + ".email"
```

Comment: This require, that everyone who calls the `Object findByEmail(String type, String email)` know in detail the structure and this I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Using SpEL should suit your needs:

```
@Query(value = "?#{ { 'communication.' + [0] + '.email' : ?1 } }")
```

The main changes are bolded out:
@Query(value = "**?#{** { 'communication.**' + [0] + '**.email' : ?1 } **}**")

This way, you can get rid of the extra quotes.

Comment: close. I don't think the ?1 will work here, but you can wrap the string operation into the SpEL like this: `@Query(value = "{ ?#{ 'communication.' + [0] + '.email' } : '?1' }")`